# OpenCL data Synchronization

Tags: multithreading, synchronization, opencl, data-synchronization

I am multiplying a row of a matrix with the inverse of the principle diagonal element of that row. I have implemented it with 1-D parallel code. All the thread runs this code

```
1.read the principle diagonal element
2.calculate the inverse of that element
3.multiply inverse with the element indexed at the thread id
```

The problem arises when ith thread in ith row executes step 3 before other thread executes step 1. It changes the value of the principle diagonal element before others can read it.

Does OpenCL have any barrier like thing which only allows a thread to execute step 3 after all threads executes step 1?

I don't want to use empty loops because there can be worst cases when it can get 
failed.

Comment: There are only barriers for workgoup wide. If your code has only one workgroup then it is possible but it is highly not adiveced if you want to run your code on GPU.

Comment: I am using a GPU and All these threads are spawned by a single call to enqueueNDRangeKernel so I guess they are in the same global work group.

Comment: No, the call spawns K Workitems (Global size) that form workgoups that each have N workitems (local size)

Comment: How large is your matrix? Why don't you output to another matrix?

Comment: I am performing reduce-raw operation on a really large matrix. Currently for testing it can be  less than 10x10. But it is supposed to work with larger size than 1000x1000.

Comment: Simply use another buffer for output data.

Comment: A 4096x4096 matrix of float value is only 1GB in size. And you can put the diagonal elements in a 1D array first if you are so short in memory. And if you plan to copy back the result to CPU right away, just do the job in CPU.

Comment: And you  need @ people, or they won't hear you.

Comment: @BlueWanderer There is no need to copy data back to CPU it is part of an intermediate calculation. I haven't used GB of data in my programming yet so I was feeling bad about using that much space. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Actually it's guilty if you left the memory you bought wasted when you can use them :S

Answer (score 0):

One way is to add `barrier(CLK_CL_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE)` .

The other way is sperating the work in two kernels, but you can pass the `cl_mem` 
 computed from step1's kernel directly to step3's kernel.This won't cause CPU/GPU IO.

The diagonal matrix multiplies a dense matrix is a set of dot product which can be done by using reduce. That will make your function faster.